# Найдите сумму чисел из представленных данных

Tags: javascript, json, объекты, методы, parse

Дана строка в формате JSON, содержащая объект с данными:

````
```
let json = `{
    "data1": [1,2,3],
    "data2": [4,5,6],
    "data3": [7,8,9]
}`;
```
````

Найдите сумму чисел из представленных данных.

из json в js перевел:

````
```
let arr = JSON.parse(json);
```
````

как теперь сложить три массива из объекта?

Comment: Вы циклы изучали?

Comment: console.log([].concat(...Object.values(JSON.parse(json))).reduce((a, b) =>{ return a + b; }, 0))

Answer (score 1):

Можно так.

```js
const json = `{
    "data1": [1,2,3],
    "data2": [4,5,6],
    "data3": [7,8,9]
}`

const arr = Object.values(JSON.parse(json))

const getArraySum = (data) => data.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)

const sumOfArrValues = arr.reduce((acc, value) => {
  return acc + getArraySum(value)
}, 0)

console.log(sumOfArrValues)
```